# Defining a Population

Tags: sample-size, population

I am tracking monthly data entry errors in a customer service dept. of 20 people, and then doing regression and correlation analysis on variables like typing speed and data entry error.

I have data spanning 5 years, which equals to 1,200 data points. The makeup of the dept. has changed during these 3 years, in that some people have left and new hires have been added. The number of people in this dept, though, remains the same at 20.

When I generalize the regression and correlation analysis results to the population (N), what is my population?

This customer service dept. across 5 years?
This customer service dept. across the entire history of the dept. (30 years)?

Is my sample size (n) equal to 1,200?

Answer (score 4):

Your population is determined by the population value you are trying to infer. It sounds like you are looking for the expected number of data entry errors per month per person, conditional on typing speed, etc. Your population then is person-months, across all possible persons who, as it were, might ever be part of your department - for practical purposes, an infinite population.

You have 1200 observations of person-months in your sample. Given that your observations are clustered (into actual persons and actual months), you would use a multilevel model, with persons and months crossed at the second level. That allows for the fact that your 1200 observations are not actually independent.